# How to insert, update, delete from remote database from within an iphone app

Tags: iphone, database

I am making an app for my msc project for which I need to connect to a remote mysql database and need to do insert, update and delete from my app.
What is the basic code for that?

I'm totally new in this platform....

Comment: Not a trivial task for homework. Did you not get any advice from the teacher on how to proceed?

Comment: no...my project teacher does not know anything about this platform...

Answer (score 1):

You can develop REST full webservices that would perform all the operations on your database. You can invoke those webservices from your iPhone app then.

Comment: hi
many many thanks for your answer.
can I ask u...how can i develop webservices. can u give me any example or any link frm where I can learn how to develop webservices for iphone app?
Thanks
regards 
srabon

Answer (score 0):

The webservices that work best for iPhone are REST full webservices. You can develop them either in Java or .Net. You may find lots of tutorials on the web related to them.
For the database you can use any one that suits your purpose like MySQL (which is open).
For Java webservices, you can look at Netbeans tutorials to develop webservices using Netbeans IDE. They would be a good starting point. Netbeans is the IDE you can use to develop REST full webservices.

The response from the webservice can be either xml or json string. You will be able to configure that.
There are lots of frameworks available for parsing either json or xml on iphone.